# Send props in .map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following props in my current component

```
static propTypes = {
    oPurchaseDetails: PropTypes.array,
    updateCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
```

Now I want to send to CartItem component. But It doesn't work there.

```
          this.props.oPurchaseDetails.map(function(item) {
            return (
               <CartItem oProductItem={item} updateCart={this.props.updateCart} />
             );
          })
```

How can I send the prop function from .map() function?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Please add the error you are getting. As long as `oPurchaseDetails` is actually an array then map should be there.

Comment: and where are using the result of map function?
`const carItems = this.props.oPurchaseDetails.map(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` accepts a second parameter that sets your `this` context:

```
this.props.oPurchaseDetails.map(function(item) {
    return (
        <CartItem oProductItem={item} updateCart={this.props.updateCart} />
    );
}, this);
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Brian mentioned, your context is changed, which is why you can't access `this` from the mapping function.

Since you are already using ES6 features, you can also use an array function:

```
this.props.oPurchaseDetails.map(item =>
    <CartItem oProductItem={item} updateCart={this.props.updateCart} />
);
```